# How to avoid log being displayed after travis_wait?

Tags: timeout, output, travis-ci, tail

`travis_wait [minutes]` allows to increase the timeout after no output has been produced to the specified argument on Travis CI. However in combination with output that exceeds the 4MB limit which I overcome by adding `&> /tmp/somefile || tail -n 10000 /tmp/somefile` the complete log is displayed after a failure, e.g.

```
$ travis_wait 30 bash -c 'mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true --batch-mode --show-version &> /tmp/tomee-build.log || tail -n 10000 /tmp/tomee-build.log'

Still running (20 of 30): bash -c mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true --batch-mode --show-version &> /tmp/tomee-build.log || tail -n 10000 /tmp/tomee-build.log

The command bash -c mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true --batch-mode --show-version &> /tmp/tomee-build.log || tail -n 10000 /tmp/tomee-build.log exited with 1.

Log:

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m -Xms512m

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

which is obviously the start of the build log instead of the last 10000 lines printed by `tail` (see https://travis-ci.org/krichter722/tomee/jobs/398814959 for details).

This works fine with a minimal setup using `python script.py &> /tmp/build.log || (tail -n 100 /tmp/build.log && exit 1)` (where `script.py` prints numbers from 0 to 1000000 each in a new line and exits with code 1 to simulate a build failure) (see https://travis-ci.org/krichter722/travis-log-exceeded/builds/400489069 for details).

Answer (score 2):

One thing I can suggest without understanding the `travis_wait` behaviour here, is to use tweak your own replacement for `travis_wait` where you can control what to do with the output in what situation. I'm using one to [eliminate the dots from the log](https://github.com/wwu-numerik/scripts/blob/762ad1f6a22c3d896e8f532c506868d78988e0e0/bash/travis_wait_new.bash).

Other than that, you could dig into the `travis_wait` [implementation](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/blob/master/lib/travis/build/templates/header.sh#L183)

Comment: Afaik the displaying of log (with the original implementation) can't happen since both stdout and stderr are redirected to a file with `&>`. Could it be that the passing of arguments is buggy and that the redirection and `|| tail -n` is interpreted to count for `travis_wait`? Otherwise I have no idea why some 100000 lines are displayed on the Travis site.

Comment: Could be. I don't understand why you're seeing the current behavior, either. It's also somewhat hard to debug imo. You could ```set +x``` before the wait command to have the bash shell print exactly what is being executed. Other than that, use the workaround I guess?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is discussed at https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8526 (the original issue is slightly different). It turns out that `travis_wait` can't track the child processes spawned by the process passed to `travis_wait`. This probably needs to be fixed on the side of Travis. There's one comment pending which someone might respond to.